# PHP syntax error for list()

Tags: php

I've never coded in php before and I'm sort of new to this and I'm helping my local community center fix up their community site and I came across a problem on the script I've been trying to fix but have no clue how can anyone offer a solution? If not them if you can point me towards the right direction to learn I'm willing to do it that way as well.

```
    if ( JmrphpbbHelper::getparam( "article_terms" ) && $view == "user" && $mode == "terms" )
{
    list(  ) = template  list ) = template    
}
```

I'm getting syntax errors from this line:

```
 list(  ) = template  list ) = template
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please put your html code here so its easy to understood.

Comment: Slapping together random terms does not an application make.

Comment: I didn't want to post it up because it a very long (line wise) file. I only know that if I can get it working I can get the site back up for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing is that its missing a semi colon. If that doesn't work, im guessing 'list(  ) = template;' ?

If you tell us what that line is suppose to do , that'd help us help you better too

Comment: Why would anybody do `list() = template;`? It's pointless.